# Derivitavie of this matrix: $\frac{d\boldsymbol{Y}}{d\boldsymbol{X}}$ of $\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{AXB}$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Well, the title is self explanatory. I want to find a closed solution of the matrix derivative. Here are the sizes of the matrices:

$[\boldsymbol{A}] = M\times N$

$[\boldsymbol{X}] = N\times P$

$[\boldsymbol{B}] = P\times Q$

$[\boldsymbol{Y}] = M\times Q$

I want to find the derivative with respect to $X$ given that,

$\boldsymbol{Y}=\boldsymbol{AXB}$

I know that if $\boldsymbol{A}$ & $\boldsymbol{B}$ are 1D matrices, that is $M=1$ and $Q=1$  then the derivative of $Y$ with respect to $\boldsymbol{X}$ is $\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{B}^T$. But this is not a general result and that ($\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{B}^T$) multiplication is invalid for $2D$ matrices.

Can anybody shade some light on the matter and/or provide some good reading materials?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you after? What does $\frac{dY}{dX}$ mean when $X$ is a matrix (as opposed to a real number)? How familiar are you with multi variable calculus?

Comment: Not much. In fact I just know some results regarding matrix calculus without knowing much details....

Comment: Well, there are many users here who can supply an answer to your question, but I'm not sure you'll be able to understand it at the moment. I'd suggest you to learn the basic definitions of multi variable calculus first, and then confront the question in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the [vec operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) to your equation, reduces it to a standard matrix-vector form
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(Y) &= {\rm vec}(AXB) \cr
  y &= (B^T\otimes A)\,{\rm vec}(X) \cr
    &= (B^T\otimes A)\,x \cr
}$$
whose gradient is well-known 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= B^T\otimes A \cr
}$$
If instead, you wanted an expression for the matrix-matrix derivative, which is a 4th order tensor, then standard matrix notation is inadequate, and you must resort to [index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) 
$$\eqalign{
  Y_{ij} &= A_{ip}\,X_{pr}\,B_{rj} \cr\cr
  dY_{ij} &= A_{ip}\,dX_{pr}\,B_{rj} \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial Y_{ij}}{\partial X_{km}} &= A_{ip}\,\bigg(\frac{\partial X_{pr}}{\partial X_{km}}\bigg)\,B_{rj} \cr
  &= A_{ip}\,\delta_{pk}\,\delta_{mr}\,B_{rj} \cr
  &= A_{ik}\,B_{mj} \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well,  $$dY = A(dX)B$$

so computing the answer is trivial (the derivative is the operator that sends $d$ to $AdB$), but there may be a psychological difficulty in imagining what "derivative" means here.  In this case it is not a number or a matrix, but a linear operator from matrices to matrices.